# Angularjs - append element with ng-show attr in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive like this:

```
.directive("test", function($compile) {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'AE';
    directive.scope = {
        options: '=testattr'
    };
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.wrap('<div class="whatever"></div>');
        var el = angular.element('<div class="test" ng-show="showBar"></div>');
        $compile(el)(scope);
        element.parent().append(el);

        scope.isOverPanel = false;
        scope.showBar = false;
        element.on('mouseover', function(){
            console.log('mouseover');
            scope.isOverPanel = true;
            scope.showBar = true;
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function(){
            console.log('mouseleave');
            scope.isOverPanel = false;
            scope.showBar = false;
        });
    };

    return directive;
});
```

For some reason the div only shows up when I *click* on *element*, not on mouseover. Also it does not disappear on mouseleave. I can see in the console that the mouseover and mouseleave events triggered.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not native angular events, so you need scope apply in both cases (mouseleave/mouseover)

```
element.on('mouseleave', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
              scope.isOverPanel = false;
              scope.showBar = false;
            });

        });
```

This is because you are using jquery to register these events and they are therefore unknown to angular and its digest cycle.

You can try to use the native angular directives to do the mouse events. Eample: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

Comment: Oh! I thought if I use jqLite (no jQuery included) it should work. I'll try the ngMouseover directive tho, see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Can't get it to work with that. `element.wrap('<div ng-mouseover="mouseOver" class="whatever"></div>');` and then `scope.mouseOver = function() { ... }`doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: you need the () in the binding. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532656/ng-mouseover-and-leave-to-toggle-item-using-mouse-in-angularjs

Comment: Right, I fixed that right after I posted here, but for some reason it's still not working.

Comment: Okay, got it. Forgot to make it an _angular.element_ and then compile. It works now! Thanks agains!