# try to change ng-class with ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this code:

Controller:

```
var ratingTotal = 5;
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.getRepeater = function() {
       return new Array(ratingTotal);
};
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="r in getRepeater() track by $index" ng-mouseover="count = count + 1" ng-mouseleave="count =count-1" ng-class="{'icon-star-full': ($index + 1) <= count, 'icon-star-empty': ($index + 1) >= count}"></span>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to make appear icon-start-full by passing mouse over the icon and disappear when leave the div but it didn't work

PD: class icon-start-full and icon-start-empty are icomoon classes

Comment: does this help you? [using mouseover in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532656/ng-mouseover-and-leave-to-toggle-item-using-mouse-in-angularjs)

Comment: Why not just set count equal to $index (or `$index + 1` if you are rating 1-5 and not 0-4) on mouseover?

Comment: @mhodges it works as you say if i remove mouseleave, but i want mouseleave too

Comment: @DavidAlzate88 Check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is evident from playing around with this code for a few minutes that the `count` variable referenced in the `ng-mouseover`, `ng-mouseleave`, and `ng-class` is not the same variable. Angular does some funky things sometimes with variable scoping like this, and so this is a perfect example of why you should always use the `controller as` syntax in AngularJS. It is well documented [Here, by Todd Motto](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) as to how and why to use it.

Here's how you can modify your code to make it work with `controller as` so you do not run into the scoping issues you are experiencing.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function (){
  var $this = this;
  var ratingTotal = 5;
  $this.count = 0;
  $this.getRepeater = function() {
    return new Array(ratingTotal);
  };
});
```

```css
.icon-star-full, .icon-star-empty {
  padding: 10px;
}
.icon-star-full {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Main">
  <div>
    <span ng-repeat="r in Main.getRepeater() track by $index" ng-mouseover="Main.count = $index + 1" ng-mouseleave="Main.count = 0" ng-class="{'icon-star-full': ($index + 1) <= Main.count, 'icon-star-empty': ($index + 1) >= Main.count}">{{$index + 1}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```